# Apache SSL reverse proxy with two name virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache reverse proxy that correctly proxies an https internal server. It is configured to use a wildcard self signed certificate and to be a name-based virtual host with ServerName directive.

I am trying to add a second https internal server to proxy, I copied the configuration from the first server, changed ServerName , but it does not work: If I try to connect to the name of the second server, it always proxies me to the first.

Here is the configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@siteX.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/siteX-cert/wildcard.siteX.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/siteX-cert/wildcard.siteX.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/siteX-cert/my-ca.crt

        ServerName      "website.siteX.com"

        CustomLog       "/var/log/apache2/website.siteX.com-ssl-access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/var/log/apache2/website.siteX.com-ssl-error.log"

        # We're not an open proxy
        ProxyRequests off

        # Proxying is available for anyone
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        # The site we're proxying through 
        ProxyPass / https://10.3.0.16/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://10.3.0.16/

        # Allows the proxying of an SSL connection
        SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@siteX.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/siteX-cert/wildcard.siteX.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/siteX-cert/wildcard.siteX.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/siteX-cert/my-ca.crt

        ServerName      "website2.siteX.com"

        CustomLog       "/var/log/apache2/website.siteX.com-ssl-access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/var/log/apache2/website.siteX.com-ssl-error.log"

        #We're not an open proxy
        ProxyRequests off

        # Proxying is available for anyone
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        # The site we're proxying through 
        ProxyPass / https://10.3.0.26/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://10.3.0.26/

        # Allows the proxying of an SSL connection
        SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does your server support SNI, i.e. at least 2.2.12? Does your browser and/or other client(s) *send* SNI?

Comment: I checked Apache version and it is  2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 , so it should support SNI. Do I have to enable it somewhere?

Comment: You shouldn't need to enable it on the server, and I've never needed to enable it on a browser that supports it (although I don't rule out the possibility); other non-browser clients vary. If you can, install and run www.wireshark.org (on Windows or Mac server or machine close to the server) while making a request or run tcpdump or similar on the server to get a capture file and move it to wireshark for easier display; expand the ClientHello and look if it contains `Extension: server_name` containing the correct name or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to Nginx and managed to get the two https sites working, with a quite simple configuration:

```
ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/siteX-cert/wildcard.siteX.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/siteX-cert/wildcard.siteX.com.key;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers  AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name website.siteX.com;
        ssl on;
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://10.3.0.16/;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name website2.siteX.com;
        ssl on;
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://10.3.0.26/;
        }
}
```